# what's the equivalent method of __init__ in Perl 6?

Tags: python, raku

In Python, `__init__` used to initialize a class:

```
class Auth(object):
    def __init__(self, oauth_consumer, oauth_token=None, callback=None):
        self.oauth_consumer = oauth_consumer
        self.oauth_token = oauth_token or {}
        self.callback = callback or 'http://localhost:8080/callback'

    def HMAC_SHA1():
        pass
```

what's the equivalent method of **init** in Perl 6? Is the method `new`?

Comment: See [Constructors](https://docs.perl6.org/language/classtut#Constructors)

Comment: Since the tag was changed to "raku", does it make sense to also update the title and body?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answers by Christopher Bottoms and Brad Gilbert are right. However, I would like to point out a few things that might make it easier to understand equivalences between Python and Perl6. 
First, [this page about going from Python to Perl6](https://docs.perl6.org/language/py-nutshell) is full with them, including [this section on classes and objects](https://docs.perl6.org/language/py-nutshell#Classes_and_Objects).

Please note that the equivalent to `__init__` in Perl6 is... *nothing*. Constructors are generated automatically from instance variables, including defaults. Calling the constructor, however, needs only the name of the class in Python, while it uses `new` in Perl 6.

On the other hand, [there are many different ways of overriding that default behavior](https://docs.perl6.org/language/objects#Object_Construction), from defining your own `new` to using [`BUILD`, `BUILDALL` or, even better, `TWEAK`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/traps#BUILD_prevents_automatic_attribute_initialization_from_constructor_arguments) (which are commonly defined as `submethods`, so not inherited by subclasses).

Finally, you do have `self` to refer to the object itself within Perl 6 methods. However, we will usually see it this way (as in the examples above) `self.instance-variable` → `$!instance-variable` (and please note that `-` can be validly part of an identifier in Perl 6).

Comment: "it's usually abbreviated"  Not sure what the "it's" refers to here.  I assume it is instance variable, but from the context of the text, this could be interpreted to be applying to `self`, which would be wrong.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, it is better now.

Comment: it could be a bit misleading to say "BUILD, BUILDALL […] or TWEAK which are called submethods". They are only submethods if you define them as `submethod`. They are commonly defined as such, and that's what makes them not inheritable. However, if you define them as `method` they'll be inheritable.

Comment: Edited too. Better now?

Comment: @timotimo Are BUILD, TWEAK, etc special methods regardless of their declaration (either as method or as submethod)?

Answer (score 11):

In Perl 6, there is the default `new` constructor for every class that you can use to initialize the attributes of the object:

```
class Auth {
    has $.oauth_consumer is required;
    has $.oauth_token = {} ;
    has $.callback = 'http://localhost:8080/callback';

    method HMAC_SHA1() { say 'pass' }
}

my $auth = Auth.new( oauth_consumer => 'foo');

say "Calling method HMAC_SHA1:";

$auth.HMAC_SHA1;

say "Data dump of object $auth:";

dd $auth;
```

Gives the following output:

> ```
> Calling method HMAC_SHA1:
> pass
> Data dump of object Auth<53461832>:
> Auth $auth = Auth.new(oauth_consumer => "foo", oauth_token => ${}, callback => "http://localhost:8080/callback")
> ```

I recommend checking out the [Class and Object tutorial](https://docs.perl6.org/language/classtut) and the page on [Object Orientation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/classtut#Constructors) (the latter page includes the [Object Construction section](https://docs.perl6.org/language/objects#Object_Construction) mentioned by Håkon Hægland in the comments to your question).

Comment: Note that you can also mark attributes as `is required` if they do not have a default value but *must* be specified.  You could also argue that Rakudo Perl 6 automatically generates the `init` method for you.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Thanks! Edited as per your suggestion. I think that the Python syntax would have made `oauth_consumer` required. It's so nice in Perl 6 not to have to list all of the public attributes twice.

Answer (score 10):

To be pedantic the closest syntactic equivalent would be to create a `submethod BUILD` (or `TWEAK`).

This is the closest translation:

```perl6
class Auth {
    has $.oauth_consumer;
    has $.oauth_token;
    has $.callback;

    submethod BUILD ( \oauth_consumer, \oauth_token=Nil, \callback=Nil ) {
        $!oauth_consumer = oauth_consumer;
        $!oauth_token = oauth_token // {};
        $!callback = callback // 'http://localhost:8080/callback';
    }

    method HMAC_SHA1 ( --> 'pass' ) {}
}
```

This is a little more idiomatic

```perl6
class Auth {
    has $.oauth_consumer;
    has $.oauth_token;
    has $.callback;

    submethod BUILD (
        $!oauth_consumer,
        $!oauth_token = {},
        $!callback = 'http://localhost:8080/callback',
    ) {
        # empty submethod
    }

    method HMAC_SHA1 ( --> 'pass' ) {}
}
```

To be really idiomatic I would write what Christopher did.